# Magento - Tier Pricing + Custom Options?

Tags: javascript, xml, magento

I currently have a Magento Store (1.8.1), with a set of products that contain several custom options (size colour etc), along with a tier price (buy 2+ and it reduces the product price).

If a customer buys 2 of the products both in red for example, they receive the discount but if they buy 1 blue and 1 red, they dont receive the discount.

Could anyone possibly help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do by configure products

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: I've tried but theres over 15 custom options for each item and 35 products, that'd be 35x15 :(

Comment: This is a fine solution, but indeed it can give us a hard time creating products when the variations are many (ie colors, sizes). I think the Magento crew should come up with a better way than using configurable products if you want flexibility with tier prices. Simple products are so easy to create for someone who doesn't need a stock management. You add variations, and a tier price. The fact that currently, tier prices apply only on 1 variation at a time, and not in combo, it's something that could well be re-designed in the core I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Tier prices for individual options are not supported by Magento. However, I went through three different options which help to realize tier prices for custom options:

- **Generating additional individual options with prices:**
  An individual option only enables one surcharge, when e.g. three are needed - one for each tier price. So you add three individual options with different prices.  The benefits of this solution are moderate changes to the system while displaying the prices for the products in a reasonable way. The solution works with two observers and additional rewrites of blocks for a better visual appearance. Once passed the checkout, Magento just works with standard custom options. Therefore, it is very unlikely to experience problems in the later steps – e.g. shipment, invoice, credit memo and export to an erp-system. The disadvantages are additional options in the backend which can be annoying when maintaining the products by hand.

In my opinion this option is best one. Although I think that it will do well for you I do not want to hold back the other two options:

- **Displaying the surcharges on basket price rules:**
  This option is the smartest one if the products are imported with an import interface from an erp-system. In this case you basket price rules can be generated – during or at the end of the import – which deliver discounts on each position. Still there is a disadvantage: The discounts on the products are shown as one sum in the checkout. Therefore this option is only useful in seldom cases.
- **Simple Configurable Product / Better Configurable Products:**
  An additional simple product is added for each variant of the product. Better Configurable Product makes sure that the tier price is taken from the simple product. However, with a lot of products and variants, it might become a bit confusing.  All these simple products must be assigned to a configurable product. Moreover, all the products have their own stock. Additionally both of the extensions use a high amount of rewrites that change the core of the Magento system.

Also there is a module as a sample for your own development. For using it you only need the entry of tier prices and individual options in the backend. After that the prices of the individual options for each tier price are entered in the newly generated options. You can request a copy fo free at http://www.code4business.de/kontakt-impressum/

If you are interested in more information about tier prices for Magento with custom options or the use of the module just have a look at http://www.code4business.de/tier-prices-for-magento-custom-options-en/